# Error Android studio + gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a big problem with android studio. I have updated text in strings.xml and now when i clean my project i have the following error in gradle console.

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"ERROR: Platform AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt","position":{},"original":"ERROR: Platform AndroidManifest.xml is corrupt"}
```

So i checkout my code before problem appears but problem persists.
I've tried several thing like clean + rebuild + update all tools and extra but nothing works.

If anybody has an idea ...

ps : I use android studio 1.3 RC 3

### EDIT (Manifest)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="***"
android:versionCode="146"
android:versionName="2.5">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<!-- Used with robospice -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!-- Permission to use camera - required -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<!-- Camera features - recommended -->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />

<permission
    android:name="***.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="***.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".TaxiApp_"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled" >

    <!-- HockeyApp Activity -->
    <activity android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity" />

    <!-- Add new meta-data mandatory -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
        tools:replace="android:value" />
    <!-- You must insert your own Google Maps for Android API v2 key in here. -->
    <!-- <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="***" /> -->
    <!-- You must insert your own Google Place API key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="***"/>
    <!-- Facebook api key -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/fb_id" />

    <!-- Facebook login activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <!-- Main activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".FirstRunActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- react to scheme -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="order" android:scheme="***" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AccountPaymentActivity_"
        android:label="@string/menu_payment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AccountPaymentResumeActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddFavoriteAddress_"
        android:label="@string/favorites"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddPaymentActivity_"
        android:label="@string/payment"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AddressNumberActivity_"
        android:label="@string/address"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AllOrderListActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".BillingAddressActivity_"
        android:label="@string/billing_address"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".BusinessActivity_"
        android:label="@string/business_options"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CardDetailActivity_"
        android:label="@string/my_cards"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CcvActivity_"
        android:label="@string/ccv_title"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChangePasswordActivity_"
        android:label="@string/change_password"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CgvActivity_"
        android:label="@string/cgv"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChooseCompanyActivity_"
        android:label="@string/company"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ChooseFavAddressActivity_"
        android:label="@string/company"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ConfirmPasswordActivity_"
        android:label="@string/comment_address"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CommentActivity_"
        android:label="@string/comment_address"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ConnectionActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ConnectionRequiredActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ConnectionSplashActivity_"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactActivity_"
        android:label="@string/contact"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactPickerActivity_"
        android:label="@string/share"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactTypeListActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ControlSmsActivity_"
        android:label="@string/validate_your_account"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CostActivity_"
        android:label="@string/cost_title"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".CountryCodeAndFlagActivity_"
        android:label="@string/country"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailPoiActivity_"
        android:label="@string/detailed_poi"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailPoiInfoActivity_"
        android:label="@string/detailed_poi"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ServicesActivity_"
        android:label="@string/discover"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EstimationActivity_"
        android:label="@string/estimation_time_cost"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EvaluateActivity_"
        android:label="@string/satisfaction_inquiry"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FaqActivity_"
        android:label="@string/faq"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FaqListActivity_"
        android:label="@string/faq"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FavoriteActivity_"
        android:label="@string/favorites"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FavoriteListActivity_"
        android:label="@string/my_favorites"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ForgottenPasswordActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity_"
        android:label="@string/menu_image"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".InterstitialActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MandatoryRefActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".MapActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/CustomToolBar"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MapInfoServLvlActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" -->
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MyAccountActivity_"
        android:label="@string/my_account"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderConfirmedActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderDetailActivity_"
        android:label="@string/your_order"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderListActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderMoreInfoActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".OutskirtActivity_"
        android:label="@string/company"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PassengerActivity_"
        android:label="@string/passenger"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PartnerResumeActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PaymentActivity_"
        android:label="@string/payment_title"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PickupPointActivity_"
        android:label="@string/rdv_point"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileActivity_"
        android:label="@string/my_profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfilePhoneActivity_"
        android:label="@string/my_profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ProfileAddFavAddressActivity_"
        android:label="@string/favorites"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PromoCodeActivity_"
        android:label="@string/promo_code"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name=".PushCenterActivity_"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity_"
        android:icon="@drawable/btn_nav_retour"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SponsorPickerActivity_"
        android:label="@string/tabClientDetailsSponsoring"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ZipCodeActivity_"
        android:icon="@drawable/btn_nav_retour"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ServiceLevelActivity_"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsHomeActivity_"
        android:label="@string/settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsHomeCardsConcurActivity_"
        android:label="@string/settings"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ShareActivity_"
        android:label="@string/share"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ThreeDSecureWebviewActivity_"
        android:label="@string/three_d_secure"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".TipActivity_"
        android:label="@string/tip_screen_title"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TrainFlightActivity_"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UserCreateActivity_"
        android:label="@string/my_account"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UserCreateFbActivity_"
        android:label="@string/my_account"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".UserCreateTwoActivity_"
        android:label="@string/my_account"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".VehiculeActivity_"
        android:label="@string/vehicle_title"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WebviewCardActivity_"
        android:label="@string/payment_title"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WebviewConcurActivity_"
        android:label="@string/concur_title"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WelcomeActivity_"
        android:label=""
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".WorldWideActivity_"
        android:label="@string/cities_covered"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <!-- Activities responsible for gathering payment info -->
    <activity
        android:name="io.card.payment.CardIOActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="io.card.payment.DataEntryActivity" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".push.MyGcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="***" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- With the new gcm, the service is optional -->


    <!-- **********     HERE IS CAPPTAIN PART     ********** -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="capptain:appId"
        android:value="${cappId}" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="capptain:gcm:sender"
        android:value="157485359661\n" />

    <!-- **********     PUSH CAPPTAIN PART     ********** -->
    <receiver android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.android.sdk.gcm.CapptainGCMEnabler" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.intent.action.APPID_GOT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.android.sdk.gcm.CapptainGCMReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="***" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- ************************************************ -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="capptain:reach:notification:icon"
        android:value="ic_launcher" />
    <!-- **********     IN APP CAPPTAIN PART     ********** -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.android.sdk.reach.activity.CapptainTextAnnouncementActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.intent.action.ANNOUNCEMENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.android.sdk.reach.activity.CapptainWebAnnouncementActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.intent.action.ANNOUNCEMENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.android.sdk.reach.activity.CapptainPollActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.intent.action.POLL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.android.sdk.reach.CapptainReachReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.intent.action.AGENT_CREATED" />
            <action android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.intent.action.MESSAGE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
            <action android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.reach.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- ************************************************** -->

    <!-- ***** Mobile App Tracking Part ***** -->
    <receiver android:name="com.mobileapptracker.Tracker" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- ************************************ -->

    <service
        android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.android.service.CapptainService"
        android:label="AppService"
        android:process=":Capptain" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="com.ubikod.capptain.ICapptainService" />

            <data android:scheme="capptain" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="capptain:api:level"
            android:value="23" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="capptain:api:id"
            android:value="***" />
        <!-- Capptain logs -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="capptain:log:test"
            android:value="${cappLog}" />
    </service>

    <!-- Spice service -->
    <service
        android:name=".spice.SpiceNetworkService"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name=".spice.SpiceLocalService"
        android:exported="false" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thx

Comment: Post your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: My manifest has not changed since a long time. All modifications are made with gradle

Comment: It can be corrupted due to a conflict for example... and as mentioned in "Twentyonehundred" answer, seems to be `<manifest>` tag that is missing.

Comment: @Rami problem with bad indent but these informations are in the manifest

Comment: I am flagging this question as not reproducible because a reboot fixed it.

Comment: @Kyll solution was so simple but it does not explain why (I've left too many time on this). I think we have to keep question because it can help other and maybe we will have a better description why this problem happens

Comment: Then you shouldn't have accepted an answer that completely disqualifies your question. As it is, it sounds like a corner-case unreproducible issue that's solved with a simple reboot. How can future users benefit of that?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

All I had to do was reboot my computer and the issue was fixed.

Comment: If rebooting the computer solved the problem, the OP's question is not reproducible. Voting to close.

Comment: Why downvotes ? My answer solved the problem... And it's not impossible that someone else will have the same issue, because I had it too. This post can help.

Comment: The downvotes are most likely from your initial edit where you swore. The community does not like unclean language. However how people decide to vote is entirely up to them. Visit [meta] for more information and to ask a question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to edited my answer, I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not have a `<manifest>` tag in there? Add

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="YOUR PACKAGE NAME">
```

after `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`.

And add an `</manifest>` after `</application>` at the end.

Comment: Sorry bad indent does not see these informations but they are here